# How to handle a long list of Exceptions in java

Tags: java

I have a webserver that catches a long list of exceptions when serving a request.

Currently we have a long list of exceptions we deal with with many catch blocks.

Is there a best practice for handling something like this?

I'm thinking of something like

```
} catch (Exception e) {
   return handleException(e);
}

Response handleException(Exception e) {
    if (e instanceof DomainException) {
       //DO SOMETHING
    } else if (e instanceof NullPointerException) {
         .
         .
         .
```

I'm not sure if this is any cleaner though. Any suggestions on a better way to handle them?

Comment: Do you handle them all the same way or do different things things?

Comment: They are handled differntly, returning slightly different responses but the logging is common between them.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with the above approach, if it suits your needs well.

Comment: It isn't. It's worse. You've deliberately thrown away the automatic selection by exception type that multiple catch blocks give you, so you have to do it again yourself manually. It's pointless. Use the language the way it was designed.

Comment: I agree EJP but I do common logging between them. I guess one option is to have a log function that takes the exception, but it's still an extra line after every catch, just wondering if there is another solution

Comment: If you need different handling, use separate catches as EJP advises. If some parts of the handling are common, factor only that portion into a common method. Do *not* discard the type-specific handling built into `catch` clauses and then try to recover it by testing for type.

Comment: What is your environment? Different web frameworks like Spring MVC or JAX-RS let you specify handler classes that are invoked for unhandled instances of exception types, meaning your handler can inherit from some base handler for the common logging, and subclasses will specify the specific details.

Comment: @EJP - If most of the logic for handling an exception is common it makes a bit of sense, especially since the handler can be taken out of line to make it easier to maintain (and possibly allow it to be shared among multiple methods).  After all, under the covers the JVM is doing an `instanceof` test to decide which handler to invoke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html) then you can club your exceptions using |  in the `catch` block. For example:

```
catch (IOException|SQLException ex)
```

Comment: And in any version of Java you can use a common superclass of multiple "need to be caught" exceptions, assuming they're all handled the same way and there's no other subclass of the common superclass you want to NOT be caught.

Comment: "assuming they're all handled the same way" therein lies the rub

Answer (score 1):

The Java 7 feature mentioned by Juned is very helpful, but I am curious why you need so many catch blocks in the first place. Whether Java 7 or otherwise, use the exception facilities of the language to your advantage.

First, make sure you aren't needlessly inventing your own `DomainException`s for situations addressed by existing exceptions like `IllegalArgumentException`.

Second, keep in mind the difference between checked and unchecked exceptions. A checked exception derives from the other side of the `Exception` class hierarchy from RuntimeException. Common checked exceptions are `IOException` and `SQLException` and must be handled. Anything subclassing RuntimeException--like `NullPointerException`--is an unchecked exception and doesn't have to be caught or thrown or anything.

Typically, you use checked exceptions for recoverable problems (where the client knows what can happen and can gracefully handle the problem and move on) and unchecked exceptions for catastrophic problems (like can't connect to the database).

If you can get past all the AOP stuff, [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/entarch/effective-exceptions-092345.html) is a great discussion of how you use checked and unchecked exceptions effectively. I think the notion of a fault barrier described there will help you cut down on the catch blocks considerably. No need to catch NullPointerExceptions anymore as you do in your sample.